# Move compiled Typescript files to parent directory grunt

Tags: typescript, gruntjs, grunt-ts

I'm having some problems trying to output my compiled Typescript files to my parent directory. Let's say I have a structure like this:

```
app
   routes
   |   src
       | test.ts
       | test2.ts
```

In this example, I want my compiled test.js and test2.js files to still appear in the routes directory, but not in an src folder. Can anyone give me some guidance? Here's what my Grunt task looks like:

```
ts: {
  app: {
    files: {
      src: ["**/\*/src/*.ts", "!node_modules/**/*.ts"],
      dest: "."
    },
    options: {
      module: "commonjs",
      noLib: true,
      target: "es6",          
      sourceMap: false
    }
  }
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want my compiled test.js and test2.js files to still appear in the routes directory, but not in an src folder.

Recommend `lib` folder:

```
app
   routes
   |   src
       | test.ts
       | test2.ts
   |   lib
       | test.js
       | test2.js
```

The option you are looking for is `outDir`.

## More

See docs https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts for more.